# PHP Submit Wrong codes to XML

Tags: php, xml

i have an xml file (scores.xml) which im using a php codes to add new Tags to it.

i have a tag called Header which contain some html code

```
<![CDATA[<tr><td colspan='7' id='headertd'>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img border='0' src='images/euro.png' />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
UEFA Euro 2012 Qualifications</td></tr>]]>
```

when im writing this code in the form of the pgp script and submiting everything goes normal to the XML file except the header tag.... im getting an error in the php script and the code is going in the xml tag like that:

```
&lt;![CDATA[&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td colspan='7' id='headertd'&gt;&#13;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#13;
&lt;img border='0' src='images/euro.png' /&gt;&#13;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#13;
UEFA Euro 2012 Qualifications&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;]]&gt;
```

so thats getting wrong info to my xml...
is there anyway i can fix this ? and avoid the transformation of these codes?

thats my php code :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {//If the user submitted the form, then add to the XML file
    //Load the scores XML file
    $scores = new DOMDocument();
    $scores -> load('../scores.xml');

    //Get the <Games> tag
    $games = $scores -> getElementsByTagName('Games');

    //Create the new <Game> tag 

    $newGame = $scores -> createElement("Game");
    $newGame -> appendChild($scores -> createElement("Header", $_POST['header']));

    //Add the new <Game> tag under the <Games> tag
    $games -> item(0) -> appendChild($newGame);

    //Save again
    $scores -> save('../scores.xml');

    echo "New game added.";
}
?>

<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
Header: <textarea style=" color:#000;" name="header" cols="73" rows="6" > </textarea>
<br><input type="submit" name="submitted" name="Add new row">
</form>
```

i have no user interface im just using this script to make work easier for me to post stuff on my website!

your help is much appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[edit 2]
Hmmmm, sorry for the wrong answer, i was thinking about it, but it's very normal that the PHP script converted it to an "encoded" form, because when you add html tags, then the xml structure will be ruined so it must be encoded. Therefore, later when you try to retrieve the data, you have to decode it with html_entity_decode() to export it properly to the browser.

[edit1]
As i see, the content is "encoded", so before saving the data decode it with html_entity_decode().
And here the "final" code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {//If the user submitted the form, then add to the XML file
    //Load the scores XML file
    $scores = new DOMDocument();
    $scores -> load('../scores.xml');

    //Get the <Games> tag
    $games = $scores -> getElementsByTagName('Games');

    //Create the new <Game> tag 

    $newGame = $scores -> createElement("Game");
    $newGame -> appendChild($scores -> createElement("Header", html_entity_decode($_POST['header'])));

    //Add the new <Game> tag under the <Games> tag
    $games -> item(0) -> appendChild($newGame);

    //Save again
    $scores -> save('../scores.xml');

    echo "New game added.";
}
?>

<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
Header: <textarea style=" color:#000;" name="header" cols="73" rows="6" > </textarea>
<br><input type="submit" name="submitted" name="Add new row">
</form>
```

Comment: can u tell me the code please? and how to use it? i don't know alot about PHP, i got help in making this script :) Thanks!

Comment: i changed this `$newGame -> appendChild($scores -> createElement("Header", html_entity_decode($_POST['header'])));` as u wrote... but it didnt work out :( i tried it with a simple html code  `<table><tr><td>something</tr></td></table>` and it was wrote on XML as `&lt;table&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;something&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/table&gt;`

Comment: hmmmm strange, could you give us a link to the full code to debug it ... ?

Comment: ok guess what :) all the problem were with the <![CDATA[ and ]]> i tried posting the HTML codes without CDATA tag which is used to post HTML codes in XML... my codes were also transformed but the output on the main page worked same as the other tags with CDATA and HTML codes... so the solution was just to removed the CDATA tags and post the HTML codes as it is and let it appear like that in XML files.. thanks for trying to help i really appreciate it :)

Comment: Hmmmm, sorry for the wrong answer, i was thinking about it, but it's very normal that the PHP script converted it to an "encoded" form, because when you add html tags, then the xml structure will be ruined so it must be encoded.
Therefore, later when you try to retrieve the data, you have to decode it with html_entity_decode() to export it properly to the browser.

Comment: i didn't have to decode it again, it was decoded alone and the results appear as i wanted on the main page, even though the codes are encodedin the xml file
if u want.. edit your answer, post the correct one and ill accept it so if someone looking for the asnwer he will find it here :)  and i cant answer my question .. i got less than 100 repu.. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) on content of `$_POST['header']` before putting it in `<Game>` tag.

Comment: can u tell me how to write it please! coz i dont know a lot about PHP! Thanks!

Comment: the example above is what you're looking for